# Can't customize font of desktop components of Windows 10 Build1803

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

I want to use a bold font for Title Bars, Menus, Message boxes, palette titles, icons and tool tips in Build 1803 of Windows 10. I didn’t find any options to do that when I searched for that.

I did Google search and I found many links like:

https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/increase-text-size-computer

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/bold-font-option-in-windows-10/9abd7069-fa50-46dc-af52-346cb7df5a45

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/bold-desktop-icon-titles-in-windows-10-home/324dfb38-8f23-40b5-9840-fa52e2d7b7b2

https://www.intowindows.com/advanced-sizing-of-text-and-other-items-removed-from-windows-10-creators-update/

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/windows-10-settings-how-to-change-advanced-sizing/e5206193-6fe4-4843-bcd7-c3a16df52f77

I have gone through all above links, but in this Windows build (1803), the options/steps explained in above links don't work, i.e., Display is not in Control Panel, and Advanced sizing of text and other items is not in Advanced Display Settings.

Please let me know, where I can find same option for making bold font in Build 1803?

In addition, I am looking for following option which is explained in almost all links:
[image: Change items and fonts of items]

The above option is available in previous Builds, but I am not able to find it in Build 1803.

I checked in three computers; HP Windows 10 Home laptop, Lenovo Windows 10 Enterprise laptop and Dell Windows 10 Pro Desktop. In all three Windows 10 is updated (i.e. Built 1803) and pre-installed/activated.

Comment: Please click on [edit] and advise two things: 1) Which of the seven editions of Windows 10 is installed? Home, Pro, Pro for Workstations, Enterprise, Education, Pro Education, or Enterprise LTSC?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions details them.  2) Have you Activated your Windows License? If you have not, on the Desktop, there will be a notice it is not Activated. Please advise.

Comment: I edited same day but not found any solution yet.

Comment: Microsoft is incredibly stupid and makes the OS worse and worse all the time.  You might have to resort to registry hacks to get this to work. Under "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics".  It really sucks that Microsoft is so S!@# these days...